# Why we should create a Maven Project for writing test scripts

Tags: maven, selenium, automated-tests

I am new to automation testing, I can't understand the purpose of creating a  Maven project for writing automation test scripts using Selenium. Can you people please guide me

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven is a dependency manager that allows you to define and import dependencies. Which means  that it can help you use libraries without having to do a lot of configuration. This could be used to set up Selenium and anything Selenium requires.

Besides that maven also allows you to specify various execution targets which can help you perform certain actions for certain purposes. You might for example want to set up a test build that will compile your program and execute all your tests, while a different target can just compile your program without the tests.

Answer (score 0):

### Maven :

**`Apache Maven`** popularly known as **`Maven`** is a **`Software Project Management`** tool. Based on the concept of a **`Project Object Model (POM)`**, Maven can manage a project's build, reporting and documentation from a central piece of information dynamically which is configured through a file **`pom.xml`**. The main advantage of using **`Maven`** are as follows :

- **Easier build process** : Maven makes the build process dynamic shielding the user from the details.
- **Uniform build system for your project** : Maven enables your project to be build using its **`Project Object Model (POM)`** and a set of plugins that are shared by all projects using Maven, providing a uniform build system.
- **Supports best practices** : Maven keeps the test source code in a separate but parallel source tree.